# Connection string for a cube in project

Tags: c#, connection-string, cube

I opened an asp project as a web site as there is no solution or project file available for it. After that I added a cube file "Data.cub" to the opened website.

I know it's probably simple but I'm new to C#, can anyone tell me how to find the connection string for this cube?